# Select() dropping items

Tags: c#, linq, select

I'm sure it's my lack of understanding.  I have a component that belongs to multiple products.  My controller action receives such a component:

```
[HttpPost] public ActionResult Create(Component model)
```

which comes fulfilled with component part ids from the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Products[0].Part.Id" value="3" />
<input type="hidden" name="Products[1].Part.Id" value="5" />
<input type="hidden" name="Products[2].Part.Id" value="2" />
```

I need to look up these values in the database and flesh the products out:

```
model.Products = model.Products.Select(x => db.Products.Find(x.Id)).ToList();
```

however, when the above runs I end up with only a single item fleshed out, as if .Select() were returning only one value.  I do have still 3 elements in .Products but the second 2 are null.

I'm sure it's just me not getting it.  how should this be done?

Comment: What is the intention of `x => db.Products.Find(x.Id)`?

Comment: Perhaps the db.Products.Find() method is simply returning null. Have you tried this in a regular foreach loop to see what happens there?

Comment: thank you both for replying.  I'm just being stupid.  the problem is `x => db.Products.Find()` needs to be `x => db.Parts.Find()` because `x.Id` is a part id, not a product id.  duh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all for replying. I'm just being stupid. the problem is `x => db.Products.Find(x.id)` is the wrong query because `x.id` is actually a part id, not a product id. duh!

Answer (score 1):

Turn the Linq statement into a foreach statement and add the items to the list manually, with List.Add().  Then you can sit with your debugger and see exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

For those queries you need to do it backwards, get the ids first into an array, then query as:

```
int[] ids = //load the ids...

var products = (from p in Products
                 where ids.Contains(p.Id)
                select p).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I should have closed this thread before (I did now) since I figured it out; but I gave up an point for offering the query anyhow